# G++ compiler giving "undefined reference" error to functions I have clearly defined

Tags: c++, g++

I have referenced several other questions on this site and others addressing this topic and nothing has helped my issue so far.

I have two classes and a main program written in c++. Total 5 files. Everything is written originally in Visual Studio 2013 and compiles and runs there.

All are in a single folder and I use this command to compile them:

g++ myprogram.cpp

I get errors "undefined reference" errors for the contructors and destructors of both classes. Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong? If not I will post my code. Thank you.

Comment: `g++ file1.cpp file2.cpp ...`

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke g++ directly like this, it will do all the steps by default, including linking. Since you haven't listed your other source files, you really just want to do compilation (it would seem) and then link the results of compiling each individual source file. You can use the "-c" option to make it just compile (rather than compile and link). Or, if you do want to build all your source files and link them together, then you should list all of the source files in question. That is:

```
g++ *.cpp -o yourexecutable # To compile and link all the sources
```

Or:

```
g++ -c yourfile.cpp -o yourobjectfile.o # To compile a single source
```

But really you shouldn't invoke g++ directly at all; there are build systems that provide a layer of abstraction on top of GCC (and other tool chains) that would be a far better, more portable, and simpler approach to building your application. For example, [Bazel](http://bazel.io/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) would be better ways to build your program from the commandline. Though not the best or most modern build system, even using Make (and relying on its implicit rules) would be better than direclty invoking the compiler.

Comment: Do you really try to say that picking a suitable build system, then learning it and then applying it is faster than writing one command line? :)

Comment: @BitTickler it depends on how complex things get. Once you start trying to link against third party libraries or break a project down into a bunch of separate libraries that are linked together, then yes, that's the case. However, my recommendation wasn't strictly on the basis of learning curve (though, yes, the build system syntax for bazel is actually way easier than the commandline invocation syntax of g++, ld, etc.), but rather on the basis of good engineering practices for a project. It's important for a project to be able to be built identically, consistently, etc...

Comment: @BitTickler ... once you have multiple programmers working on a project, having a consistent one word command to do the entire build is way better than sharing or copying+pasting a set of invocations to perform. It's also important for build automation, testing, etc.

Comment: Oh really! You are on a mission here! And I thought he just wanted to get his 5 files compiled :)

Comment: Some people don't have enough knowledge to ask the right questions, so when I answer things on StackOverflow, I try to understand what they are trying to accomplish, and give them a more complete answer that guides them towards engineering best practices, even if it may be more or different than what they had in mind. My answer does address the OPs question, but it also provides additional high level direction. I personally see no issue with that, but to each their own.